# Can't mount EFS in the ECS instance

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I have this UserData in the `configurationConfig` resource in my cloudformation template:

```
"UserData":{  "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -xv\n",
              "yum -y update\n",
              "yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
              "yum -y install awslogs jq\n",
              "#Install NFS client\n",
              "yum -y install nfs-utils\n",
              "#Install pip\n",
              "yum -y install python27 python27-pip\n",
              "#Install awscli\n",
              "pip install awscli\n",
              "#Upgrade to the latest version of the awscli\n",
              "#pip install --upgrade awscli\n",
              "#Add support for EFS to the CLI configuration\n",
              "aws configure set preview.efs true\n",
              "#Get region of EC2 from instance metadata\n",
              "EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`\n",
              "EC2_REGION=",{ "Ref": "AWS::Region"} ,"\n",
              "mkdir /efs-tmp/\n",
              "chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /efs-tmp/\n",
              "DIR_SRC=$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE.",{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "FileSystemMap", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "FileSystemID"] },".efs.$EC2_REGION.amazonaws.com\n",
              "DIR_TGT=/efs-tmp/\n",
              "touch /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "echo ",{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "FileSystemMap", {"Ref" : "EnvParam"}, "FileSystemID"] }," >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "echo $EC2_AVAIL_ZONE >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "echo $EC2_REGION >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "echo $DIR_SRC >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "echo $DIR_TGT >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "#Mount EFS file system\n",
              "mount -t nfs4 -o vers=4.1 $DIR_SRC:/ $DIR_TGT >> /home/ec2-user/echo.res\n",
              "#Backup fstab\n",
              "cp -p /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.back-$(date +%F)\n",
              "echo -e \"$DIR_SRC:/ $DIR_TGT nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0 | tee -a /etc/fstab\n",
                      "docker ps\n",
              "service docker stop\n",
              "service docker start\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
              "         --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
              "         --resource ContainerInstances",
              "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
              "service awslogs start\n",
              "chkconfig awslogs on\n"
            ]]}
```

Here is the security group of the ECS container:

```
  "EcsSecurityGroup":{
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "ECS SecurityGroup",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "2049",
          "ToPort" : "2049",
          "CidrIp" : {"Ref" : "CIDRVPC"}
        },
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "22",
          "ToPort" : "22",
          "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "SecurityGroupEgress" :  [
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "-1",
          "FromPort" : "-1",
          "ToPort" : "-1",
          "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "VpcId":{ "Ref":"VpcId" }
    }
  },
```

After running the template, I ssh into the instance, waited for `userdata` to finish executing, then I found in `/var/log/cloud-init-ouptut.log` this error:

```
mount.nfs4: Connection timed out
```

Moreover, the `/etc/fstab` file does not contain the mount line.
And I can't access the File system, because the created folder for EFS is empty..

Please tell me where is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you created EFS security group and allow your ec2 security in the ingress rules:

```
 "EfsSecurityGroup": {
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "EFS security group",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 2049,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                        "Ref": "YOUR_EC2_SECURITY_GROUP"
                    },
                    "ToPort": 2049
                },
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Application",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "efs-sg"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "YOUR_VPC_ID"
            }
        },
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    }
```

Ensure EFS mountarget exist:

```
"EFSMountTargetYourAZ": {
        "Properties": {
            "FileSystemId": "EFS_id",
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "EFS_SECURITY_GROUP"
                }
            ],
            "SubnetId": {
                "Ref": "SUBNET_ID"
            }
        },
        "Type": "AWS::EFS::MountTarget"
    },
```

Comment: In your ec2 security group, you should not have the ingress rule for port 2049 which is for EFS, you should create an efs security group and allow your ec2 security as `SourceSecurityGroupId` on that port 2049.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's a typo (missing closing `\"`) in this line in your script, which is causing the attempted write to `/etc/fstab` to fail:

   ```
   echo -e \"$DIR_SRC:/ $DIR_TGT nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0 | tee -a /etc/fstab\n",
   ```

   This should read:

   ```
   echo -e \"$DIR_SRC:/ $DIR_TGT nfs4 nfsvers=4.1 0 0\" | tee -a /etc/fstab\n",
   ```
2. You need to make sure that an [`AWS::EFS::MountTarget`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-efs-mounttarget.html) resource exists in the availability zone specified. Otherwise, the attempt to mount the filesystem using the DNS name will fail to resolve correctly. See [Mounting File Systems](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html) and [`AWS::EFS::FileSystem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-efs-filesystem.html) for further documentation.